# Outlook recipients fields appear double

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Don't know if this is the right forum to ask, but here goes.

After installing Office 365, I am experiencing the following screen from Outlook when trying to send an email.

[Outlook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp7yV.gif)

Have you seen this before and what can be done to change it?

Comment: Reboot and try again. That's what I'd start with for a problem with the Outlook UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try repair office: To do this, please go to Control Panel > Programs and Features. Right click your Office suit and then choose Change. Click Repair.

If that doesn't help, create a new profile in case some personal settings may be corrupted:

Open Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles > Add. Follow the instruction to configure the account.